# Como passar por parametro em um Action Link valores que estao em elementos HTML?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho 2 elementos HTML, um `TextBox` e um `Hidden`, que possuem valores, como passar pro parametro no Action link os valores desses elementos? Abaixo os parametros `docItemId` e `vlrImobIcms` estao dando erro.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Valor imobilizado do ICMS", new { @class = "col-xs-4 control-label" })
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        @Html.TextBox("VlrImobilizado", "", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        @Html.ActionLink("Gerar Parcelas", "Gerar", new { bemId = @ViewBag.BemID, docItemId = ItemSelecionado.value, vlrImobIcms = VlrImobilizado.value }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-sm" })
        @Html.Hidden("ItemSelecionado", "")
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: não conheço muito destas linguagens, porém conheço HTML e POO na minha opinião acho que o problema é porque os valores `"VlrImobilizado"` e `"ItemSelecionado"` estão vazios e a criação do objeto necessita que todos tenham valores `não nulos`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você terá de usar javascript para poder colocar os parâmetros dos seus `input`s `text` e `hidden` como parâmetros no link.

O valor do hidden, talvez possa ser colocado diretamente no link, no lado do servidor, caso o valor do mesmo não seja alterado no browser... o que tornaria o hidden inútil no caso de ele nunca ser submetido através de um form.

**Exemplo usando jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#actionLinkId").on("click", function () {
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            url += ((url.indexOf('?') == -1) ? '?' : '&');
            url += $.param({
                docItemId: $("#ItemSelecionadoId").val(),
                vlrImobIcms: $("#VlrImobilizadoId").val()
            });
            $(this).attr("href", url);
        });
    })
</script>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Valor imobilizado do ICMS",
        new { @class = "col-xs-4 control-label" })
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        @Html.TextBox("VlrImobilizado", "",
            new { @class = "form-control", id = "VlrImobilizadoId" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        @Html.ActionLink("Gerar Parcelas", "Gerar",
            new { bemId = @ViewBag.BemID },
            new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-sm", id = "actionLinkId" })
        @Html.Hidden("ItemSelecionado", "valor-qualquer",
            new { id = "ItemSelecionadoId" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: o `Hidden` seria um `<input type=hidden>` ?

Comment: @PauloRoberto Sim, no ASP.NET MVC é possível criar um input hidden assim: `@Html.Hidden( ...parâmetros... )` ou usando markup mesmo.

Comment: Humm... e O Segundo parâmetro do `ActionLink` seria o HTML ID dele? e o primeiro parâmetro das `TextBox` seriam também o HTML ID deles?

Comment: O segundo é o valor, já vou editar a resposta, mostrando como fazer usando jQuery... ai vou colocar ID nos elementos... é mais fácil explicar exemplificando.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo postei ser ver tua atualização, seria bem esta minha sugestão. +1, abçs

Comment: @AndreCalil Demorei um pouquinho pra atualizar, tenho pouco tempo pra ficar aqui... pois estou no trabalho.